# Assert.Inconclusive analogue for MS C++ unit testing framework or how to skip test on the run?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, microsoft-cpp-unit-test

I want to be able to skip a current test from its body. Of course, I could simply do this:

```
if (condition) return;
```

But this will show the test as "passed". I want to keep the user informed that the test is neither passed nor failed if `(condition)` happens.

In C# we have `Assert.Inconclusive()`, so some C++ analogue of this function would be the best. Is there anything like this in *Microsoft Cpp Unit Testing Framework* or can it be implemented?

Comment: are you using [tag:mstest] or [tag:microsoft-cpp-unit-test]?

Comment: @AlanBirtles MS Cpp Unit Testing Framework. I corrected my question

Comment: Doesn't look like it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/microsoft-visualstudio-testtools-cppunittestframework-api-reference?view=vs-2019